# SQL Server Compact - Is the DB connection disposed when the app crashes?

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server-ce, database-connection, crash

I am using a **SQL Server Compact Edition DB** in a **WPF application**.

I create one connection to the DB and keep it open for the life of the app - the connection is only closed and disposed when the application exit event fires.

What happens if there is an app crash? Will the connection be disposed automatically when the application process dies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an UnhandeledException handler to your app, and close the global connection there, if it is still open. Even if the app crashes, the database connection will shout Down when the appdomain shuts Down, you can test by crashing the app, and see if you can delete the database file from File Explorer.

Comment: Ok, so the DB connection is shutdown when the app crashes. Would it be the AppDomain.UnhandledException event or Dispatcher.UnhandledException event where I close the connection?

Comment: AppDom.Unhandeled Exception

Answer (score 0):

SQL Connection, FileStream .... are managed code but they use unmanaged unmanaged resources as well so they are not under direct control of the GC. You need to make sure you dispose these objects. Good practice is using() keyword that will call dispose when exiting from the scope.

You will have memory leak if you don't close these resources.

Comment: I am aware of the disposing of resources and the using() keyword. However, what if there is an app crash? Is there an event that fires for that? I guess not. Will the DB connection remain alive till the PC restarts?

Answer (score 0):

No, the connection will not be disposed automatially when the application process dies. It is not advised to have a active db connection for long time. When your application makes frequent visits to db, [connection pooling](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17768/ADO-NET-Connection-Pooling-at-a-Glance) is an option.

Comment: Opening and closing connections to a SQL Compact DB is an expensive process and it is recommended to keep it open. Also, SQL Server Compact does not have connection pooling. See: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stevelasker/archive/2008/10/31/pdc-2008-embedding-sql-server-compact-in-desktop-and-device-applications.aspx